# How can I make the 1 string in a txt file to separate lists?

Tags: python, pandas, txt

### Heading ##Transcription from audio to txt file.

From txt file to a Pandas DataFrame.

[Random.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgQ2V.png)

```
with open('random.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)  
    f.close()
```

Current output:

['0.68', '2.54', 'Yes, I believe so.']['3.74', '4.04', ' Agree']['6.74', '8.3', 'I, also agree']

Desired output:

| Start | End | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.68 | 2.54 | Yes, I believe so. |
| 3.74 | 4.04 | Agree |
| 6.74 | 8.3 | I, also agree |

I expect to use regular expressions for this, but I'm also open for other solutions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show the content of the text file, maybe the first 3 lines?

Comment: @MarcoHannemann the content from the text file looks like this: 
['0.68', '2.54', 'Yes, I believe so.']['3.74', '4.04', ' Agree']['6.74', '8.3', 'I, also agree']
It is a small section of the file, but the complete txt file looks like this.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your file contains string representations of lists, you should parse them with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('/tmp/random.txt', 'r') as f:
    df = (pd.DataFrame(map(literal_eval, f),
                       columns=['Start', 'End', 'Text'])
            .astype({'Start': float, 'End': float})
         )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Start   End                Text
0  0.68  2.54  Yes, I believe so.
1  3.74  4.04               Agree
2  6.74   8.3       I, also agree
```

Input file:

```
['0.68', '2.54', 'Yes, I believe so.']
['3.74', '4.04', ' Agree']
['6.74', '8.3', 'I, also agree']
```

---

If you file is a single line:

```
['0.68', '2.54', 'Yes, I believe so.']['3.74', '4.04', ' Agree']['6.74', '8.3', 'I, also agree']
```

Then you first need to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) the string with a regex:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

with open('/tmp/random.txt', 'r') as f:
    df = (pd.DataFrame(map(literal_eval, re.split('(?<=\])(?=\[)', f.read())),
                       columns=['Start', 'End', 'Text'])
            .astype({'Start': float, 'End': float})
         )
```

Comment: @Yermo please provide the exact content of your file

Comment: thank for you reply. Your code generates the following error: ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Subscript object at 0x000001B068C9FA90>

Comment: @Yermo please don't use an image but paste directly the content as **text**. It looks like you have a single line (which doesn't match your original code); then you should `split` the string.